# Дата между вчера и сегодня, запрос в методах DateAdd и DateDiff

Tags: sql, база-данных, дата

```sql
WHERE SomeDate >= DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()),'21:00:00')
AND SomeDate < DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,1,GETDATE()),'21:00:00')
```

По итогу необходимо получить дату между вчера с девяти вечера до сегодня девяти вечера.

Прочитала документацию, подскажите кто знает, правильно ли создала запрос

[DATEADD](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

[DATEDIFF](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

может лучше использовать ?

```
BETWEEN
```

Comment: По поводу between. Когда sql создавался, он позиционировался, как язык для домохозяек, приближенный к разговорному английскому. В этом случае произносить between намного проще. Но программерам, по аналогии с другими языками программирования, привычнее использовать операторы сравнения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WHERE SomeDate >= DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,1,GETDATE()),'21:00:00')
AND SomeDate < DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()),'21:00:00')
```

```sql
DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()),'21:00:00') --сегодня до девяти
```

```sql
DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,1,GETDATE()),'21:00:00') --вчера с девяти
```

в моем случае в запросе были перепутаны больше меньше

> = / <